# Write a program to sum 2 numbers

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Hi I'm tring to write an exercise to sum 2 numbers between 0 and 9, the problem is that when I can only have results up to 15 after that it will go back to 0 if  the result is 17 it will display 1.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
#make_COM#

; COM file is loaded at CS:0100h
ORG 100h

;*******************************
;*    Programa: CONDIC4.ASM    *
;*******************************

.MODEL small
.STACK 512d

.DATA
  msg1 DB 'Decimal 1 (0 to 9): ', 024h
  msg2 DB 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Decimal 2 (0 to 9): ', 024h
  msg3 DB 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Sum = ', 024h
  msg4 DB 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Invalid', 024h

.CODE
  LEA   DX, msg1
  CALL  write
  CALL  read
  MOV   BH, AL

  LEA   DX, msg2
  CALL  write
  CALL  read
  MOV   BL, AL

  LEA   DX, msg3 
  CALL  write
  XCHG  AX, BX

  ADD   AL, AH
  SUB   AH, AH
  AAA
  MOV   DX, AX
  MOV   AH, 0Eh
  CMP   DH, 0h
  JE    not_zero
  OR    DH, 30h
  MOV   AL, DH
  INT   010h
  not_zero:
  OR    DL, 30h
  MOV   AL, DL
  INT   010h
  INT   020h

write PROC NEAR
  MOV   AH, 09h
  INT   021h
  RET
write ENDP

read PROC NEAR
  MOV   AH, 01h
  INT   021h
  CMP   AL, 030h
  JL    erro
  CMP   AL, 03Ah
  JGE   erro
  SUB   AL, 030h  
  RET
  erro:
    LEA   DX, msg4
    CALL  write
    INT   020h
  RET
read ENDP
```

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Learn to use a debugger so you can single step your program and find the error yourself.

Comment: I am single line debugging but I can't understand the error I'm getting when I run AAA command

Comment: Describe the error and what you see as input and output to `AAA`. Consult the instruction set reference to see what the expected behavior is. Pay attention to the part where it says _"The AAA instruction is only useful when it follows an ADD"_. You put a `SUB` in between and that destroys the flags needed.

Comment: BY what I read of the AAA if my input if 0Fh it will store in AH 01h AL 05h, but if my input is 12h it will store in AH 00h and AL 02h. WHY?

Comment: Oh so I shouldn't use sub ah,ah? How I empty ah?

Comment: WHY? Because that's how it works. Have you read the manual? To empty `AH` reorganize the code so it can be done before the `ADD`. For example: `MOVZX AX, BL; ADD AL, BH; AAA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fixed it using the MOV (MOV AH, 0h) command instead of SUB (SUB AH,AH) since the manual says MOV won't change any flag.

```
#make_COM#

; COM file is loaded at CS:0100h
ORG 100h

;*******************************
;*    Programa: CONDIC4.ASM    *
;*******************************

.MODEL small
.STACK 512d

.DATA
  msg1 DB 'Decimal 1 (0 to 9): ', 024h
  msg2 DB 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Decimal 2 (0 to 9): ', 024h
  msg3 DB 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Sum = ', 024h
  msg4 DB 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Invalid', 024h

.CODE
  LEA   DX, msg1
  CALL  write
  CALL  read
  MOV   BH, AL

  LEA   DX, msg2
  CALL  write
  CALL  read
  MOV   BL, AL

  LEA   DX, msg3 
  CALL  write
  XCHG  AX, BX

  ADD   AL, AH  
  MOV   AH, 0h     ;Clears AH WITHOUT CHANGING FLAGS
  AAA
  MOV   DX, AX
  MOV   AH, 0Eh
  CMP   DH, 0h
  JE    not_zero
  OR    DH, 30h
  MOV   AL, DH
  INT   010h
  not_zero:
  OR    DL, 30h
  MOV   AL, DL
  INT   010h
  INT   020h

write PROC NEAR
  MOV   AH, 09h
  INT   021h
  RET
write ENDP

read PROC NEAR
  MOV   AH, 01h
  INT   021h
  CMP   AL, 030h
  JL    erro
  CMP   AL, 03Ah
  JGE   erro
  SUB   AL, 030h  
  RET
  erro:
    LEA   DX, msg4
    CALL  write
    INT   020h
  RET
read ENDP
```